# how can I remove box2d body shape outline?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Is there a way to remove (or make transparent) a box2d body shape outline so doesn't appear when the sprite is moving though it is still there?

Comment: Can you please explain briefly your question?

Comment: If you want to make sprite transperent than you can decrease its opacity.By Default it's opacity is 255.

Comment: you want to remove debug draw?

Comment: @Rao27: the box2d shapes in my code overlap. I want the body shapes to be transparent not the sprite so that only the sprite is seen.

Comment: @Andrew: I am not sure. would removing the debug draw solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Debug draw from your code.. this will solve your issue..

Debug draw is just to check all the bodies that you have created are working as you wanted..